# Can you stream a video in AR without it saving to the device with ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit

I am trying to make an app that plays videos in AR on a flat surface. It is working but the videos take up too much space on the device. I was wondering if there was a way to stream the videos live with an internet connection in AR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!

Apple revealed this year, as part of *RealityKit*, something called **Video Materials**!

This can be loaded from a URL.

See the following:
https://maxxfrazer.medium.com/realitykit-videomaterials-66ad05f396f4